# why the pid of process which is created with fork() and exec() finally changed

Tags: linux

I start a process with fork and exec,but when I use `ps` like `ps afx | grep sublime` to look up the pid, I found that these two pids(one is fork() return value,the other is the `ps` result) are different.

my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int create_process(char *name, char *argv[])
{
    int pid = fork();
    if (0 == pid)
    {
        execv(name, argv);
        exit(127);
    }
    else if (0 < pid)
    {
        return pid;
    }else
    {
        return -1;
    }
}

int forkstyle_system(char *cmdstring)
{
    int pid = fork();
    if (0 == pid)
    {
        execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", cmdstring, (char *)0);
        exit(127);
    }
    else if (0 < pid)
    {
        return pid;
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }
}

int main()
{
    //method 1
    char *name = "/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text";
    char *argv[] = {"/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text", (char *)0};
    int pid = create_process(name, argv);
    printf("pid = %d\n",pid);

    //method 2
    /*
    char *cmdstring = "/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text";
    int pd = forkstyle_system(cmdstring);
    printf("pid = %d\n",pd);
    */
    return 0;
}
```

the result of method 1

[image]

the result of method 2

[image]

I feel very confused，because I think，in the child, the use of execv() is irrelevant; that doesn't change the pid.

Comment: Looks like `sublime_text` uses `fork()` internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like @Barmar is correct here ... internally sublime text is creating one (well ... there is definitely more than one) child here ... most likely with `fork()`. You can tell from the `clone` call below that sublime is creating children.

```
[acripps@localhost Code]$ strace -e trace=%process /opt/sublime_text/sublime_text 
execve("/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text", ["/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text"], 
0x7ffff4607370 /* 56 vars */) = 0
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7fb6fa15b740) = 0
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, 
child_tidptr=0x7fb6fa15ba10) = 32653
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

And here we can see the pids, as described in the question. Please note the `child_tidptr` value from strace: it corresponds with the actual PID of sublime, rather than

```
[acripps@localhost Code]$ ps afx | grep sublime
32675 pts/0    S+     0:00  |   |   \_ grep --color=auto sublime
32653 ?        Ssl    0:00  \_ /opt/sublime_text/sublime_text
32670 ?        Sl     0:00      \_ /opt/sublime_text/plugin_host 32653 --auto-shell-env
[acripps@localhost Code]$
```

if you were to use something a little simpler, like `sleep` for example, you would find that the pids line up with your expectations:

```
[acripps@localhost Code]$ ./exec_m1 
pid = 1696
Press ENTER to continue ...
[acripps@localhost Code]$ ps afx | grep sleep
1696 pts/1    S+     0:00  |   |       \_ /usr/bin/sleep 300
1711 pts/2    S+     0:00  |       \_ grep --color=auto sleep
```

or, using method 2:

```
[acripps@localhost Code]$ ./exec_m2
pid = 1774
Press ENTER to continue ...
[acripps@localhost Code]$ ps afx | grep sleep
1774 pts/1    S+     0:00  |   |       \_ /usr/bin/sleep 300
1776 pts/2    S+     0:00  |       \_ grep --color=auto sleep
```

An interesting point to note, is that you use `"/bin/sh -c"` in method 2 ... this step shouldn't be required. IIRC, when not attached to a tty the shell will simply call one of the `exec` family of functions to replace itself with the executable ... if the shell *is* attached to a TTY, though, it will go through another `fork` call first.

There's lots of really good information in the [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/), but it may take several readings to really sink in ... also, checking out the source code of a POSIX OS and trying to understand the process management pieces will really help solidify the understanding. I did this with QNX neutrino, but FreeBSD is another really good one to check out.

For this exercise, I modified your `main()` function a little bit, to be easier to use:

```
int main()
{
    int pid = 0;

#if METHOD == 1
    //method 1
    char *name = "/usr/bin/sleep";
    char *argv[] = {name, "300", (char *)0};
    pid = create_process(name, argv);
#else
#if METHOD == 2
    //method 2
    char *cmdstring = "/usr/bin/sleep 300";
    pid = forkstyle_system(cmdstring);
#endif
#endif

    printf("pid = %d\n",pid);
    printf("Press ENTER to continue ...");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

which can be compiled like so:

```
gcc -o exec_method1 -DMETHOD=1 exec.c
gcc -o exec_method2 -DMETHOD=2 exec.c
```

... I got lazy and used the preprocessor, ideally (if this were the start of a tool you want to keep around), then you would want to parse `main`'s `argv` to tell you which method to use, and where to find the executable/provide args for the executable. I leave that as an exercise for the reader ;-)

Comment: If I need start process with fork and exec,what could I get the pid? Search /proc or there is another simple/efficient method?

Comment: You should be able to use `ptrace()` to trace systemcalls (I have not yet done this, but [This Article](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6100) goes through some of the details (also check `man 2 ptrace`); if you can grasp that and play with the code, then you should be able to grab child pids.

Comment: Otherwise, it seems that using proc is the way to go ... there's some source [here](https://github.com/tmm1/pstree/blob/master/pstree.c) that prints a process tree, check out the definition `struct Proc` and then open `/proc/${pid}/status` (where ${pid}` is the pid of the sublime process), and then copy the contents into a Proc struct and look up the child process. (Disclaimer: I have not yet done this on linux, so it may take some experimentation)